# How to loop <TR> rows within Table in WebBrowserControl?

Tags: vb.net

I have a web page that I am trying to pull data elements from.  I am trying to figure out how to loop the  tags in the web page, contained within the specific "TABLE" tags shown.

```
    Dim ProductionRpt = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ProductionReport").Children
    For Each row As HtmlElement In ProductionRpt
        MsgBox(row.InnerText)
    Next row
```

The above code is what I am trying to do with the table rows, only the code above returns the innertext for the table html element, and not any of the  tags contained within the table. Perhaps this is expected if you are only looking at the table element itself (which is indeed what I told it to do) and not any of the rows.  How do I loop through all the  tags so I can get access to the data I want?  Is there another way besides using `.GetElementsByTagName?`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're expecting to find inside those rows... If you're sure to find `0` or `1` level of `<a>` tags you should simple create additional `If` statements and `Loop` to check using `GetElementsByTagName` like you said. Even if you had more tags to check for you could iterate through a list of "expected tags".

If you don't know how many nested elements inside each row you're going to find then you should probably create a recursive function and look for any child element (and its value) inside a row before continuing to the next one.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81tad23s.aspx